# Maven profile does not affect module earlier in project list

Tags: maven

Why won't my run configuration using a maven profile work as intended? Why does the profile fail to skip tests while the parameter does work as intended?

I have a maven run configuration which doesn't run as intended (it runs tests in `lib-module` which I want skipped):
`-pl common,lib-module,my-module test -PdontTestLibProfile`

When I run the same run config but using the maven property parameter directly:
`-pl common,lib-module,my-module test -DdontTestLib=true`  the skipping of lib-module tests succeeds.

The maven profile `dontTestLibProfile` lives in the pom of `my-module`.

```
<artifact-id>my-module</artifact-id>
[...]
<profile>
    <id>dontTestLibProfile</id>
    <properties>
        <dontTestLib>true</dontTestLib>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

`dontTestLib` is a mavenProperty which is checked in the `lib-module`, where if it is set to `true` it will not run integration or unit tests.

```
<artifactId>lib-module</artifactId>

<properties>
    <!-- Skip tests: Default is to NOT skip ==> Default is to run -->
   <doneTestLib>false</dontTestLib>
</properties>

[...]

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Skip Lib-Module Integration tests if skip is set -->
                <skipTests>${dontTestLib}</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Skip Lib-Module Unit tests if skip is set -->
                <skipTests>${dontTestLib}</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Some corollary questions which might be the cause of this issue:

- Do maven profiles run in the same sequence as the project list itself, not allowing `my-module` to affect the `lib-module` which comes before it?
- Do profiles only affect their own POM/module and I am trying to reach outside of the scope?